# Как сделать так чтобы выводились буквы от a до z в python?

Tags: python, массивы

Дан такой код :

```
from random import choice,random
alfa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', 
'1',
    '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ',', ':', ';', '!', 
'?', ' ']


dct = {str(i) : [] for i in range(10)}
print(dct)
```

В этом коде
`dct = {str(i) : [] for i in range(10)}`
будет возвращать числа от 0 до 9 . И у меня вопрос: что нужно вписать в `dct` чтобы он возвращал не числа от 0 до 9, а буквы от a до z?

Comment: Не знаю python, но 10 минут в гугле и пяток экспериментов -- `dct = {chr(i) : [] for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)}`

Comment: Осталось только понять, а причем тут список alfa ?

Answer (score 1):

Делать за вас ваше домашнее задание не буду, но подскажу, что метод .isalpha позволяет проверить является -ли символ буквой, а функция filter  -  позволяет применить некоторую функцию ко всем элементам составного объекта (список -  является составным объектом, если что). Этих знаний достаточно, что-бы написать ответ.